# After updating from vue 2.1 to 2.5, vue stopped working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I recently updated from vue 2.1 to vue 2.5.

I have used vue-cli to create the project and then moved the previous 2.1 project's components to src folder.

After that I started receiving an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'components' of undefined
at checkComponents (vue.esm.js?e1b2:1321)
at mergeOptions (vue.esm.js?e1b2:1442)
at mergeOptions (vue.esm.js?e1b2:1458)
at Vue$3.Vue._init (vue.esm.js?e1b2:4528)
at new Vue$3 (vue.esm.js?e1b2:4646)
at eval (main.js?3479:41)
at Object../src/main.js (app.js:5655)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
at fn (app.js:89)
at Object.0 (app.js:5928)
```

My main.js in as below:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import { store } from './store'
import mixins from './mixins'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes.routes
  // mode: 'history'
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  store: store,
  mixins: [mixins]
})
```

Here is the App.vue file as requested:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <el-container>
    <navbar v-if="loggedIn"></navbar>
    <el-aside style="width:auto; z-index:9999; ">
      <sidebar v-if="loggedIn"></sidebar>
    </el-aside>
    <el-main style="width:auto;">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </el-main>
  </el-container>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Sidebar from './page_components/Sidebar'
  import Navbar from './page_components/Navbar'
  export default {
  components: {
    Sidebar,
    Navbar
  }
}
```

I am getting the error in following line in vue.esm.js:

[image: Error]

Comment: Could you also share the file ./App?

Comment: @Manish Updated.

Comment: My hunch is that one or all of your mixins are defined incorrectly. Do you get the error if you remove `mixins: [mixins]` from App?

Comment: Also try doing a `console.log(mixins)` and see what is in that object

Comment: Thanks. That helped I needed to add export.default in Vue.mixin({}).

Comment: is the components imported correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where an update also stopped my Vue app for no obvious reason and was saying undefined like you're experiencing here.

The simple solution was to add `.default` to the end of all my components when registering in my `app.js` file.

`Vue.component('nav-container', require('./components/nav/nav-container.vue').default);`